# How to use the result of an SQL statement in a math expression?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two SELECT statements that return a number each, and I'd like to divide one by the other.
Something like the following, if it would work:

```
SELECT
    SELECT
        SUM(SIZE)
    FROM
        GLOBAL_STATS_V_M
    WHERE
        ID IN ("DuplicatedRule", "OldRule", "RevRule", "TmpRule")
/
    SELECT
        SUM(SIZE)
    FROM
        GLOBAL_STATS_V_M
    WHERE
        ID IN ("Total")
```

That gets a 'Query Error: near "SELECT": syntax error Unable to execute statement'.

Adding parenthesis does not help.

How to do this?

I'm using Sqliteman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add parenthesis:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT
        SUM(SIZE)
    FROM
        GLOBAL_STATS_V_M
    WHERE
        ID IN ("DuplicatedRule", "OldRule", "RevRule", "TmpRule")
    )
    /
    (SELECT
        SUM(SIZE)
    FROM
        GLOBAL_STATS_V_M
    WHERE
        ID IN ("Total")
    )
```

Comment: I *thought* I had already tried this, but copy-pasting this code worked! I suppose I typoed it the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems here.

1. You need parenthesis around both sub select statements.
2. You need to finish the outer statement with FROM DUAL.

   select
        (select ....) / (select ....) as total
     from 
        dual

I actually would prefer to write the query differently for cleanliness.

```
select subtotal.total / alltotal.total
  from (select sum(size) as total .... where id in ("Duplic....) ) subtotal,
       (select sum(size) as total .... where id in ("total") ) alltotal
```

Comment: Dual is for Oracle but not for SQLite